# Is it possible to access google calendar programmaticaly without having a user to login?

Tags: .net, google-calendar-api

I have a list of username and passwords and want to access google calendar with these. Can I authorize programmaticaly or do I have to login manualy for every user?

Comment: What do you mean by "authorize programmatically" and "login manually"?

Comment: Yes and no; there is a  [google calendar API](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/), but access may be more difficult than simply username/password (the [full details are here](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/v3/using.html#auth)), and may need the user to log in through their OAuth API. As a general rule, you probably shouldn't *have* the passwords for users.

Answer (score 1):

You want the Google Data API Setup msi from

http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/downloads/list

The Calendar app does exactly what you want: authenticates a request with a (gmail) username/password and reads the calendar.